# create a list that will send me an email when someone signs up under that time

Tags: 2013, list, custom-list

So my thing is I am trying to learn how to use sharepoint 2013 more and what better a way to incorporate in my little project. 
I would like to create a list that people can go to and sign up for a time. 
After that they sign up, I would like to get an email with that time so i can schedule it on my calendar.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: So what i did was create a custom list and i will have the times available and all the person needs to do is sign up for a time slot. I have made it so only open times will show. When someone makes a change i will get an email notification. i would like it to be directly added to my outlook exchange. any ideas

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to make a list with whatever columns of information you need (such as Name, Date, Time, etc) then subscribe for an email alert to send you alerts when any new items are added to the list.

Or another simple approach:  instead of making a list you could make a calendar, which really is just a very special type of list, and again use alerts to notify you of additions. You can even synchronize the SharePoint calendar with your Outlook calendar so new events are viewable in Outlook automatically.

But if you need more functionality, such as only allowing a specific time to be reserved by one person at a time, it's definitely possible but would take a more advanced approach. The methods above would allow users to make overlapping requests.

Comment: After i make the Calendar I would have to use advanced coding to make it so multiple people couldnt use the same time?